# Socket loses connection randomly

Tags: python, windows, sockets

I have socket querying a Prologixx GPIB to ETH0. I got the code to do this by friends. In Win 10, the socket randomly get a timeout, sometimes the computer seems to close the connection. I would like to recognise, that there is a problem with the socket to be able to start it again.

There are two messages:

> _recv [WinError 10035] A non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately

This only yields invalid results and I am taking care of by checking if the results is sensible. It is also only temporarily

> _send [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

This is permanent. The programs runs as before, just dies not get new results. Testing for new results is difficult, because they are temperature and my be stable for a while.

```py
import socket
from numpy import nan
from time import sleep
class PrologixGPIBEthernet:
    PORT = 1234

    def __init__(self, host, timeout=1):
        self.host = host
        self.timeout = timeout

        self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,
                                    socket.SOCK_STREAM,
                                    socket.IPPROTO_TCP)
        self.socket.settimeout(self.timeout)

    def connect(self):
        self.socket.connect((self.host, self.PORT))

        self._setup()

    def close(self):
        self.socket.close()

    def select(self, addr):
        self._send('++addr %i' % int(addr))

    def write(self, cmd):
        self._send(cmd)

    def read(self, num_bytes=1024):
        self._send('++read eoi')
        return self._recv(num_bytes)

    def query(self, cmd, buffer_size=1024*1024):
        self.write(cmd)
        return self.read(buffer_size)   

    def _send(self, value):
        encoded_value = ('%s\n' % value).encode('ascii')
        try:
            s = self.socket.send(encoded_value)
        except Exception as e:
            print('_send', e)

    def _recv(self, byte_num):
        try:
            value = self.socket.recv(byte_num).decode('ascii')
        except Exception as e:
            print (',_recv', e)
            value = 'ERROR'
        return value

    def _setup(self):
        # set device to CONTROLLER mode
        self._send('++mode 1')

        # disable read after write
        self._send('++auto 1')

        # set GPIB timeout
#        self._send('++read_tmo_ms %i' % int(self.timeout*1e3))

        # do not require CR or LF appended to GPIB data
#        self._send('++eos 3')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the error messages but it sounds similar to my experience.

The prologix device is what I would call an "interpreter" as it doesn't seamlessly work with SCPI.

For example, for a normal SCPI instrument I can ask the device to perform a measurement then I can ask to read that measurement and it will give me a response when it's done. As long as I have a large timeout it will hang until the buffer is filled then return the result. (Note: This is not how you should do it. Using polling or an interrupt are good ways to implement device queries.)

The prologix device can get confused with the timing. If I try to copy how SCPI will work (like mentioned above) by sending a command to read a measurement, but this time it takes 5 seconds to make that measurement and put it in the buffer. Before the 5 seconds has elapsed I ask the prologix what the result is it will try and find a result but the buffer is empty so it has nothing to return. After the 5 seconds the buffer gets filled but the prologix doesn't know this and gets stuck in this state. This is where you get the socket timeout.

The proper way to solve this this to use the polling feature in the prologix to work out when the buffer has a result. But this isn't something I've got round to doing.

Hack 1) Make sure there is a big enough delay but you don't always know how long you need and will add loads of delay to your script.

Hack 2) Deliberately force your script to timeout and retry. This is what I have implemented. I know it's ugly but it was a quick hack that worked while I was trying to work out what the problem was.

```
def read_timeout_poll(self, repeat):
    # start_time = time.time() # Used if you want to see how long it takes
    mesg = ""
    for _ in range(repeat):
        try:
            sendData = "++read\n"
            self.prolSock.send(sendData.encode())
            mesg = self.prolSock.recv(self.BUFSIZ)
            break
        except socket.timeout:
            time.sleep(1)
        except socket.error as e:
            return "Python Error sending data: " + str(e)
            break
    # print(f"read poll operation took {:.0f} seconds".format(time.time() - start_time)) # This is a guide to see how long it takes to get a result in the buffer
    return mesg
```

Answer (score 0):

Dear Zircatron thanks for you r answer and suggestions. The randomly happening timeout is not so problematic, I do as you suggest, just try again after a while. Mot problematic is the condition when (the prologixx?) closes the connection. In the end, I will have to reestablish the connection when the timeout happens several times without a functioning return. Even more ugly, but I am running out of ideas...

Answer (score 0):

It's stupid that we can't comment on each other's response in stackoverflow because we don't have enough reputation.

I feel like I'm only half understanding the problem. To help, what sequence are the errors occurring and what are you trying to send when it happens? can you give and example of the code that leads up to the errors?

Your code comment says "# disable read after write" however, you have it enabled "self._send('++auto 1')". I would disable it. I find that enabling it doesn't allow you to have full control of the command sequence.

Comment: The errors occur randomly and I only read from the serial port. I dont send anything.

Comment: Sorry, the <enter> was too quick. It just sends some commands to the PROLOGIXX to configure it.  Because of the randomness of the error, example code would not help much. As written I would like to tregocnize when the connection has been broken off. I can deal with occasionally occuring read failures.

Comment: As in recognise the drop out compared to the time out? Couldn't you use two different exceptions? like socket.timeout and socket.error?